# How to get mocha with chai assert to report file/line number?

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I'm using `mocha` with `chai.assert` for my tests. Errors are caught and reported, but they don't show a file/line number where they happen. I'm used to having location information with tests in other languages, it's otherwise hard to figure out which assert failed.

Is there some way to get location information with mocha/chai/assert?

Comment: you need to mock requests with mocha ?

Comment: At the moment I'm just doing basic sync testing.

Comment: I think this will help you ...and sorry if i grabbed the content of the question wrongly ..http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/28/mocking-requests-with-mocha-chai-and-sinon/

Comment: I'm looking for the source file name and line number where the assert failed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From version [1.9.1 onwards](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md#191--2014-03-19), if you set the [`includeStack` flag](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#configure) to `true`, you'll get a stack trace on assertion failures:

```
var chai = require("chai");
chai.config.includeStack = true;
var assert = chai.assert;

describe("test", function () {
    it("blah", function () {
        assert.isTrue(false);
    });
});
```

In versions prior to 1.9.1 you had to set `chai.Assertion.includeStack = true`. From 1.9.1 onwards this method of getting stack traces is deprecated. It is still available in 1.10.0 but may be removed in 1.11.0 or 2.0.0. (See [here](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md#191--2014-03-19) for details.)

The example above will show a stack trace where `assert.isTrue` fails. Like this:

```
AssertionError: expected false to be true
      at Assertion.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:193:10)
      at Assertion.Object.defineProperty.get (.../node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addProperty.js:35:29)
      at Function.assert.isTrue (.../node_modules/chai/lib/chai/interface/assert.js:242:31)
      at Context.<anonymous> (.../test.js:7:16)
      [... etc ...]
```

(I've truncated the trace to what is only relevant and truncated the paths.) The last frame shown in what I've included above is the one where the error happened (`.../test.js:7:16`). I do not think that chai allows having *only* the file name and line number of the assertion call.

Comment: It shows a stack trace, but all the line numbers are wrong. Perhaps it has something to do with using coffee-script as the input file... I suppose this is the answer nonetheless.

Comment: The issue of getting stack traces that reflect coffee-script line number is a different question entirely. The entity responsible for producing the stack trace is the JavaScript VM, not Chai or Mocha.

Answer (score 8):

`chai.Assertion.includeStack` is now deprecated. Use `chai.config` instead

```
var chai = require("chai");
chai.config.includeStack = true;
var assert = chai.assert;
```